# I keep getting Database Error Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value

Tags: php, cakephp, phpmyadmin

Hey I keep getting the following error when completing a form on the site I am building and cannot figure out why.

```
Database Error
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: ' ' for column 'product_id' at row 1

SQL Query: INSERT INTO `ahbtest`.`user_products` (`product_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (' ', 8)

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\pdo_error.ctp
```

Here is the code for my form's view:

```
<form method="post" action="/admin/users/add_favorites<?= isset($userId) ? "/" . $userId  : ""; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class='row form-group'>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>Products</h3>
                <?php foreach($products as $product):
                    ?>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input id="checkBox"  name='data[Product][]' value=" <?php $product['Product']['id']; ?>" type="checkbox">
            <label><?php echo $product['Product']['name']; ?></label>
            </div>
                <?php
                endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>



<?php // echo $this->Form->hidden('Product.id'); ?>
<?php // echo $this->Form->hidden('Product.parent_id', array('value' => $parentId)); ?>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save Changes</button>

</form>
```

And here is the code for my form's controller:

```
public function admin_add_favorites($userId = null){

    ini_set('memory_limit', '2G');

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $error = false;
            $this->loadModel('UserProduct');
            if(!isset($userId))
                $userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
            foreach($this->request->data['Product'] as $product)
            {
                $this->UserProduct->create();

                if(!$this->UserProduct->save(array('product_id' => $product, 'user_id' => $userId)))
                        $error = true;
            }
             if (!$error) {
                $this->Session->setFlash("Favorites have been successfully added.", 'flash_success');
                return $this->redirect('/admin/users/favorites');
            }
            else {
                   $this->Session->setFlash("One or more errors occurred. Please try again.", 'flash_error');
            }
        }
        if(isset($userId))
            $this->set('userId', $userId);
        $this->loadModel('Product');
        //$this->set('products', $this->Product->find('list', array('fields' => array('id', 'name'))));
        $product = $this->Product->find('all', array('fields' => array('id', 'name')));
        $this->set('products', $product);
          //pr($product); 
    }
```

Any idea why this would be happening or how to stop it?  I can attach the structure of my database tables if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, turns out I was not actually passing an id to the database. Under the view I had 
`value=" <?php $product['Product']['id']; ?>"`
but when I changed it to `value="<?= $product['Product']['id']; ?>"` the system read the product id correctly.  I assume that it is some sort of error with the `<?php` prefix I was using compagred to `<?=`.

Comment: simply you were missing an `echo`

Comment: so Does <?= not require echo while <?php does?

Comment: `<?=` is a short form for `<?php echo`